# or-tools - add constraint to jobshop problem

Tags: or-tools

I would like to extend a bit the job shop example given [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop).

Given each machine has power consumption and at any given time (duration unit) there's a max power consumption on all machines, i would like to prevent overlap only if the sum of all machine consumptions passes a fixed value.

```cs
var allJobs =
new[] {
  new[] {
    // job0
    new { machine = 0, duration = 3, power = 5 }, // task0
    new { machine = 1, duration = 2, power = 2 }, // task1
    new { machine = 2, duration = 2, power = 1 }, // task2
  }.ToList(),
  new[] {
    // job1
    new { machine = 0, duration = 2, power = 5 }, // task0
    new { machine = 2, duration = 1, power = 2 }, // task1
    new { machine = 1, duration = 4, power = 1}, // task2
  }.ToList(),
  new[] {
    // job2
    new { machine = 1, duration = 4, power = 1 }, // task0
    new { machine = 2, duration = 3, power = 2 }, // task1
  }.ToList(),
}.ToList();
```

The "[flexible job job](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/flexible_job_shop_sat.py)" example covers interval overlap but not the sum of a new variable and with the addon of this must be checked on every duration unit.

Any pointers on how i can achieve this?

Regards

Comment: This is the cumulative constraint.

Comment: hello,
yes,  from the documentation, it seams the right way to go. thanks.
nevertheless im kinda strugling to find examples using it.
any pointers?

Comment: Rcpsp_sat.py, jobshop_sat.cc both examples use the cumulative constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed that's the way to go.

i was able to implement it using your directions.
then i tryed to extend it a little further using the same method.

each machine, has a 'type', and and sum of power per 'type' could not exced a given value.
i grouped the intervals by type then call noOverlap on them.
But ive making a mistake somewhere as it aint correctly calculating despite give a solution.

```
//id, type
    var machinesTypes = new[] {
        1, 1, 2
    };

    var allJobs =
        new[] {
            new[] {
                // job0
                new { machine = 0, duration = 3, power = 5, type = 1 }, // task0
                new { machine = 1, duration = 2, power = 4, type = 1 }, // task1
                new { machine = 2, duration = 1, power = 2, type = 2 } , // task2
            }.ToList()
        }.ToList();

    int numMachines = 0;
    foreach (var job in allJobs)
    {
        foreach (var task in job)
        {
            numMachines = Math.Max(numMachines, 1 + task.machine);
        }
    }
    int[] allMachines = Enumerable.Range(0, numMachines).ToArray();

    // Computes horizon dynamically as the sum of all durations.
    int horizon = 0;
    foreach (var job in allJobs)
    {
        foreach (var task in job)
        {
            horizon += task.duration;
        }
    }

    // Creates the model.
    CpModel model = new CpModel();



    //full power capacity Constraint 
    IntVar full_power_capacity = model.NewIntVar(0, 11, $"full_power_capacity");
    CumulativeConstraint cc_full_power = model.AddCumulative(full_power_capacity);


    //type power constraint
    Dictionary<int, CumulativeConstraint> cc_all_machines = new Dictionary<int, CumulativeConstraint>();
    foreach (int machine in allMachines)
    {
        int machineType = machinesTypes[allMachines[machine]];
        if (!cc_all_machines.ContainsKey(machineType))
        {
            IntVar type_power_capacity = model.NewIntVar(0, 6, $"type_power_capacity_{machineType}");
            CumulativeConstraint cc_type_power = model.AddCumulative(type_power_capacity);
            cc_all_machines.Add(machineType, cc_type_power);
        }
    }


    Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<IntVar, IntVar, IntervalVar>> allTasks = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<IntVar, IntVar, IntervalVar>>(); // (start, end, duration)
    Dictionary<int, List<IntervalVar>> machineToIntervals = new Dictionary<int, List<IntervalVar>>();
    Dictionary<int, List<IntervalVar>> machineTypesToIntervals = new Dictionary<int, List<IntervalVar>>();
    for (int jobID = 0; jobID < allJobs.Count(); ++jobID)
    {
        var job = allJobs[jobID];
        for (int taskID = 0; taskID < job.Count(); ++taskID)
        {
            var task = job[taskID];
            String suffix = $"_{jobID}_{taskID}";
            IntVar start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, "start" + suffix);
            IntVar end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, "end" + suffix);
            IntervalVar interval = model.NewIntervalVar(start, task.duration, end, "interval" + suffix);
            var key = Tuple.Create(jobID, taskID);
            allTasks[key] = Tuple.Create(start, end, interval);
            if (!machineToIntervals.ContainsKey(task.machine))
            {
                machineToIntervals.Add(task.machine, new List<IntervalVar>());
            }
            machineToIntervals[task.machine].Add(interval);

            cc_full_power.AddDemand(interval, task.power);


            string suffix_2 = $"_{task.type}";
            IntVar start_2 = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, "start_2" + suffix_2);
            IntVar end_2 = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, "end_2" + suffix_2);
            IntervalVar interval_2 = model.NewIntervalVar(start_2, task.duration, end_2, "interval_2" + suffix_2);
            if (!machineTypesToIntervals.ContainsKey(task.type))
            {
                machineTypesToIntervals.Add(task.type, new List<IntervalVar>());
            }
            machineTypesToIntervals[task.type].Add(interval_2);

            cc_all_machines[task.type].AddDemand(interval_2, task.power);

        }
    }

    // Create and add disjunctive constraints.
    foreach (int machine in allMachines)
    {
        model.AddNoOverlap(machineToIntervals[machine]);
    }


    foreach (var item in cc_all_machines)
    {
        model.AddNoOverlap(machineTypesToIntervals[item.Key]);
    }
     
    // Makespan objective.
    IntVar objVar = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, "makespan");
     
    model.Minimize(objVar);

    // Solve
    CpSolver solver = new CpSolver();
    CpSolverStatus status = solver.Solve(model);
```

Comment: removing the "cc_all_machines" loop and not creating "interval_2" worked

Comment: what if i wanted that any job could not start if any other job, from the same machine or not, has ended on previous duration unit?

(for example, to give a duration to clean the floor before the machine starts to work)

Comment: i know that i need to store the machine ends, then loop all tasks and check "model.Add(machine_starts[j2] >= machine_ends[j1] + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)"
like it is done in the "single_machine_scheduling_with_setup_release_due_dates_sat"
but im unable to get it to work

Comment: any pointers? kinda stuck here

Answer (score 1):

For each task, create an interval. Use this interval in the no_overlap constraint of the corresponding machine.

Then add a cumulative constraint with the fixed value from the description as capacity.

Then for each task, add a demand (interval of the task, power of the task) to the cumulative constraint using this method: https://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/classGoogle_1_1OrTools_1_1Sat_1_1CumulativeConstraint.html#a922ab6a70999c054e9e94aa2dfb96be4